# What does it mean when pytest fixture yields from another fixture instance?

Tags: pytest

This is the real code from MLflow: https://github.com/mlflow/mlflow/blob/8a7659ee961c2a0d3a2f14c67140493a76d1e51d/tests/conftest.py#L42

```py
@pytest.fixture
def test_mode_on():
    try:
        prev_env_var_value = os.environ.pop(_AUTOLOGGING_TEST_MODE_ENV_VAR, None)
        os.environ[_AUTOLOGGING_TEST_MODE_ENV_VAR] = "true"
        assert is_testing()
        yield
    finally:
        if prev_env_var_value:
            os.environ[_AUTOLOGGING_TEST_MODE_ENV_VAR] = prev_env_var_value
        else:
            del os.environ[_AUTOLOGGING_TEST_MODE_ENV_VAR]

@pytest.fixture(autouse=True, scope="session")
def enable_test_mode_by_default_for_autologging_integrations():
    """
    Run all MLflow tests in autologging test mode, ensuring that errors in autologging patch code
    are raised and detected. For more information about autologging test mode, see the docstring
    for :py:func:`mlflow.utils.autologging_utils._is_testing()`.
    """
    yield from test_mode_on()
```

There are also multiple places where `test_mode_on` is used like this:

```
@pytest.mark.usefixtures(test_mode_on.__name__)
def test_safe_patch_propagates_exceptions_raised_outside_of_original_function_in_test_mode(
```

When I try to run any tests I get the following:

```
tests/test_version.py::test_is_release_version ERROR                     [100%]

==================================== ERRORS ====================================
Fixture "test_mode_on" called directly. Fixtures are not meant to be called directly,
but are created automatically when test functions request them as parameters.
See https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/fixture.html for more information about fixtures, and
https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/deprecations.html#calling-fixtures-directly about how to update your code.
```

I want to understand what the original code was doing with `yield from test_mode_on()` and how to fix it.

Update:
I've tried to change the code to request the fixture, but got an error that `test_mode_on` has function scope while `enable_test_mode_by_default_for_autologging_integrations` has session scope.

```py
@pytest.fixture(autouse=True, scope="session")
def enable_test_mode_by_default_for_autologging_integrations(test_mode_on):
    """
    Run all MLflow tests in autologging test mode, ensuring that errors in autologging patch code
    are raised and detected. For more information about autologging test mode, see the docstring
    for :py:func:`mlflow.utils.autologging_utils._is_testing()`.
    """
    yield from test_mode_on()
```

Answer (score 1):

The intention obviously was to re-use a function-scoped fixture in a session-scoped fixture. Apparently, this was an option that was working in old `pytest` versions.

In any recent `pytest` version, this is not possible (as you have noticed). If you cannot fix the `MLflow` tests, your only option is to use an old `pytest` version that still supports that - `MLflow` has pinned `pytest` to 3.2.1 (probably for that same reason).

Be aware that any `pytest` plugin you have installed will likely not work with that `pytest` version either, so you have to downgrade or remove the plugins, too.

[This recent issue](https://github.com/mlflow/mlflow/issues/4616) is probably related to the outdated `pytest` version, so there is a chance that this will be addressed in `MLflow`.

*UPDATE*:
Just realized that it would help to show how to fix this for a current `pytest` version. In current `pytest` you are not allowed to derive (or yield) from a fixture with a narrower scope, as this would often not work as expected. You can, however, move the fixture code into a generator function, and yield from that. So a working version could be something like:

```py
def test_mode_on_gen():
    try:
        prev_env_var_value = os.environ.pop(_AUTOLOGGING_TEST_MODE_ENV_VAR, None)
        os.environ[_AUTOLOGGING_TEST_MODE_ENV_VAR] = "true"
        assert is_testing()
        yield
    finally:
        if prev_env_var_value:
            os.environ[_AUTOLOGGING_TEST_MODE_ENV_VAR] = prev_env_var_value
        else:
            del os.environ[_AUTOLOGGING_TEST_MODE_ENV_VAR]

@pytest.fixture
def test_mode_on():
    yield from test_mode_on_gen()

@pytest.fixture(autouse=True, scope="session")
def enable_test_mode_by_default_for_autologging_integrations():
    yield from test_mode_on_gen()
```